# Elmah, convert to .Net4 vs2010, run on server 2008, does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008, elmah

So I've been using elmeh forever.

I've got an app I've recently converted to MVC3  .net4, and vs2010, and it's developed on a server 2008 box (as opposed to my other apps developed on an XP box).

I set up elmah normally and it does not work...

I've got a reference to ELMAH.dll already, it's in my CommonDLLs folder.

I add the sectiongroups

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
             <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
</sectionGroup>
```

I add the sections

```
<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/ELMAH" />
    <!--<errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />-->
    <errorMail from="change.me@CCCC.org" to="brown.ericw@CCCC.org" subject="Application: StudentPortal3G,  Environment:Dev, ServerBoxName: Dev" async="true" />
</elmah>
```

I add the module and handlers

```
<httpHandlers>
            <add verb="*" path="*.pdfx" type="JCDCHelper.Web.UI.RunAsASPXHandler, JCDCHelper.Web" />
            <add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
</httpModules>
```

I add the SMTP section for Email support

```
 <system.net>
    <!--Required for Elmah Mail Processing-->
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="10.10.10.10" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

I goto the "~\ELMAH" folder, select my machine, and give the network service account full control of the folder (did the same for Everyone, just in case)

I set up the routing for elmah.axd to go throguh as a web page.

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");
```

I add a location tag, so I can hit elmah.axd without being logged in

```
<location path="elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <!--<deny users="?" /> in prod and qa change to this, otherwise anyoen can look at the logs - EWB-->
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

But I get nothing, no elmah emails, no XML logs in the ELMAH folder, and a 404 when I goto elmah.axd

What am I missing? ANy help is appreaicted.

Thanks,

Cal-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under IIS7 you need to add the httpHandlers and httpModulea under the system.webserver node of the web.config.

This thread should help: http://groups.google.com/group/elmah/browse_thread/thread/4bbef2f26e0c5fd1

Comment: Per that article I add the <system.webServer> section, but now I get "unable to start webserver, when I try to debug in VS2010. If i comment it out, it works fine. I added it right after the </system.web> tag. Any ideas? I tried it with and without rmmoving them from the normal Handler and Modules aslo.

Comment: Figured it out, I alredy had a web server section that was added by the converstion tool, can't have two of those! thanks!

Comment: Same problem here - Win Server 2008 r2 is very particular about "modules", where as Win 8 IIS7 is not. So if you have *two* "modules" sections within your system.web, on Win 8 it will be fine, but Win Server 2008 R2 will error 500 if you do that. So check that your ELMAH modules are in the same "modules" section as any other modules you may have installed. Been there, done this.

This is particularly nasty if your second "modules" section is added by a production web.config transform...