# Elmah not seeing database

Tags: asp.net, web-config, elmah

We are moving to a new production web server and sql server.  I have my application up and running, except that Elmah does not log any errors and the elmah.axd file says that there are no entries in the database.  I am guessing that somehow, our userid is messed up.  The elmah section of my web.config is:

```
<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1"/>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="DBConnectionString"/>
</elmah>
```

My DBConnectionString is:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=....;User Id=....;Password=....;Initial Catalog=cms_stagedb3;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

The user id has the Execute permission set on the elmah sprocs.  there are entries in the web.config module section and the system.WebServer.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: Can your servers see each other through the network to even make a connection?

Comment: Yes, the servers see each other.  The application works when connecting to the database.  elmah is the only thing that doesn't seem to see anything.  Obviously, something could be wrong, but I don't see it right now.  :-/

Comment: I wonder if there could be some type of issue where the elmah code can't see database but the iis server can see the database.  The elmah code should run in the iis process, so it should get it's security context, but I wonder about this.  Thoughts?

PS. Yeah, I know its a reach. :-/

Comment: Maybe look at the comment stream on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659926/elmah-fails-to-login-to-db-on-production-but-not-test-server. It sounds a bit like the same problem and there are definitely some ideas for things to look into.

Comment: I'm thinking the problem is the application name.  When i never set it, the app name is pulled from the name provided by the web server.  new web server, new name.